# SQL queries which achieve minimum results when inner-joining two tables (in terms of the number of rows)

Tags: sql

**OrderID     CustomerID      OrderDate** 
10308           2           1996-09-18   
10309           77          1996-09-19   
10310           77          1996-09-20

**Customer ID     CustomerName      Address             City**  
1                      Alfreds              Maria Anders  Berlin  
2                      Ana                   D.F.  05021    Mexico  
77                    Antonio             D.F.    05023     Mexico

Question : When inner joining two tables above, I'd like to see the result like below:

**CustomerID       OrderID**  
2                       10308  
77                     10309,10310

Are the order of the steps below correct? and could you please instruct me what SQL method are needed for each step?

1. inner join two tables
2. merging order id for the same customer id
3. deleting duplicated rows for the same customer id

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please specify (and tag appropriately) which database are you using.

Comment: In Oracle, you can use LISTAGG (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030). For other databases, you can easily google for LISTAGG in [database] and find SO questions with answers.